# removing existing timeseries from dataset in Jfreechart

Tags: eclipse, time-series, jfreechart, e4

I am using eclipse e4. I have three timeseries which has inputs dynamically from GUI.

```
/*some code to calculate the entries from a hashmap*/
for (i = 0; i < statValue.length; i++) {

            if(statValue[i].equals("MIN"))
            {
            timeseries[i] = new TimeSeries(entries.getKey()+statValue[i],Second.class);
            }
            if(statValue[i].equals("MAX"))
            {
            timeseries[i] = new TimeSeries(entries.getKey()+statValue[i],Second.class);
            }
            if(statValue[i].equals("AVG"))
            {
            timeseries[i] = new TimeSeries(entries.getKey()+statValue[i],Second.class);
            }       

/* some code to calcluate the input to the timeseries */

if(statValue[i].equals("MIN")){
            for(Entry<Timestamp,Long> seriesData : MinutesToMin.entrySet()){

                System.out.println(new Second(seriesData.getKey())+" "+seriesData.getValue());
                timeseries[i].add(new Second(seriesData.getKey()), seriesData.getValue());
            }
            dataset.addSeries(timeseries[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("MAX");
            if(statValue[i].equals("MAX")){
            for(Entry<Timestamp,Long> seriesData : MinutesToMax.entrySet()){

                System.out.println(new Second(seriesData.getKey())+" "+seriesData.getValue());
                timeseries[i].add(new Second(seriesData.getKey()), seriesData.getValue());
            }
            dataset.addSeries(timeseries[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("AVG");
            if(statValue[i].equals("AVG")){
            for(Entry<Timestamp,Long> seriesData : MinutesToAvg.entrySet()){

                System.out.println(new Second(seriesData.getKey())+" "+seriesData.getValue());
                timeseries[i].add(new Second(seriesData.getKey()), seriesData.getValue());
            }
            dataset.addSeries(timeseries[i]);
            }
```

}

After the series are displayed in Jfreechart. In my code the timeseries may change depending on the "statValue" that I select from my GUI. The timeseries gets dynamically added. I do not want to add the timeseries if it is already present. How to check if timeseries is already present and is it is present I want to remove it.?

Answer (score 2):

Every [TimeSeries](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) has a key to identify it.  To see if a TimeSeries exists in a [TimeSeriesCollection](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeriesCollection.html) use the [getSeries(Comparable)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeriesCollection.html#getSeries%28java.lang.Comparable%29) method in that class - it will return null if there is no series with that key.  If it returns a non-null value, then you can call the [removeSeries(TimeSeries)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeriesCollection.html#removeSeries%28org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries%29) method to remove it.